# How interpret or what's the meaning of rbm.up results?

Tags: recommender-system, rbm

I am studying deep learning and the deepnet R package gives me the following example: (rbm.up function Infer hidden units states by visible units)

```
library(deepnet)

Var1 <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
Var2 <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50))
x3 <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
r1 <- rbm.train(x3, 3, numepochs = 20, cd = 10)
v <- c(0.2, 0.8)
h <- rbm.up(r1, v)
h
```

The result:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.5617376 0.4385311 0.5875892
```

What do these results means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation mentions, it shows the hidden states of each of the nodes in the restricted Boltzmann machine after you have trained your model. The number of values you get from `rbm.up` is equal to the value for the `hidden` argument in `rbm.train` (the second value), which in your case is 3. If you increase this number you will see that the number of values you get from `rbm.up` also increases:

```
library(deepnet)

Var1 <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
Var2 <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50))
x3 <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
r1 <- rbm.train(x3, 5, numepochs = 20, cd = 10)
v <- c(0.2, 0.8)
h <- rbm.up(r1, v)
print(h)

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.5826883 0.6624397 0.5545223 0.4133155 0.5533788
```

Comment: Thanks @Oxbowerce. I was reading about recommendation systems using RBM, but at the moment i don't understand how these outputs can be used for. I will keep me studying and searching.